# Make an encrypted partition visible to any operational system

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

So, what I'm facing is not a problem really, is more of a question. I have a 1TB external usb 3.0 hard drive, it works perfectly, and no problems with it. I usually store movies, photos, installers from softwares I use, backups, all of that on it, as well as some personal things, like scanned documents and personal pictures.

I was wondering if there's any way that I can make an encrypted partition/folder, that can be seen and accessed in any OS, so like, if I lend my hard drive to a friend that uses Windows he will have access to the movie, but not the info in the encrypted partition, and if I'm in Linux(or Windows) and I need something from my "sensitive information" encrypted partition, I can have it.

So, summarizing:

- How can I make an encrypted partition/folder?
- Can I make that encrypted partition visible in both OS?

Sorry for any grammar mistakes, or wrong tags. Hope this question is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) is the replacement for the now discontinued former 'industry standard' multi-platform encryption tool, TrueCrypt.

**For Ubuntu/Linux:** Download and extract the `VeraCrypt Linux Setup 1.18` (current version). Run the file with "setup-gui" in its name and x86 or x64 according to your system's architecture.

**For Windows:** Download and run the Windows installer.

It's very easy to use but you should also read the [user guide](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1601971).

Comment: thanks, I'll check it out. If that's what I'm looking for I'll mark your answer as correct.